# how to append data into new line of the file on SD card?

Tags: c, append, card

I need to append data into a file on SD card in new line every time the data is appended.
for example:

```
data: "this is my data 40"
```

Output file content after append:

first iteration of loop:

```
this is my data 40
```

second iteration of loop:

```
this is my data 40this is my data 40
```

I want the data be appended in new line every time like this:

first iteration of loop:

```
this is my data 40
```

second iteration of loop:

```
this is my data 40
this is my data 40
```

```c
sd_answer = SD.appendln(file,data);
sd_answer = SD.appendln(file,"");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tag your question with the programming language you are using?
Your tags are not really helpful.

Comment: I am using C programming

Comment: do you have code? Can you post it? What errors occur?